# jQuery qTip: disable on hidden elements

Tags: jquery, mouseover, hidden, qtip

I'm using jQuery qTip to provide tooltips on a set of buttons, but the buttons are initially hidden by default until another action on the page triggers them to display. However, my qTip tooltips are still appearing if you mouseover where the hidden buttons are located on the page.

Since I'm fading the buttons in, I need to animate their `opacity` from `0` to `1`, so I can't hide the buttons totally with `display: none` (which I believe is why they're still reacting to the `mouseover` event). Is there any way I can disable the tooltips when the `opacity` is `0`?

Comment: Hiding buttons and making them appear all of a sudden isn't a good programming practice. Consider disabling them instead.

Comment: The buttons are disabled already; the purpose is to simplify the page visually by hiding buttons that can't be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that qTip tips won't trigger on elements with `visibility: hidden`, so I fixed this by setting both the `opacity` and the `visibility` on the buttons' container:

```
#button-container {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then toggling the `visibility` before animating the `opacity`:

```
$('#button-container').css({visibility: 'visible'}).animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
```

Comment: Glad you were able to find the solution.  This is my approach too but with `display: none;`

Comment: `display: none` works too, but I had to use `visibility: hidden` because `#button-container` is floated and it throws some other things off if I hide it entirely. That's just my particular case though.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable qTips:

`$('*').qtip('disable')`  // or specify the selector

There is also an enable:

`$('*').qtip('enable')`

Basically in the callback for your fade in, enable the qtips.